# Why does this unsafe block return a unit type?

Tags: rust, unsafe

I haven't quite understood how `unsafe` and assignments work together. The following code gives me some error:

```
fn num() -> u64 {
    1;
}

fn test() -> u64 {
    let x = unsafe {
        num();
    };
    return x;
}
```

The error is:

```
src/main.rs:37:9: 37:10 note: expected type `u64`
src/main.rs:37:9: 37:10 note:    found type `()`
```

My real [example](https://github.com/ucarion/rust-lxc/blob/master/src/container.rs#L42) is similar to this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Semicolons.

```rust
fn num() -> u64 {
    1
}

fn test() -> u64 {
    let x = unsafe {
        num()
    };
    return x;
}
```

[See also this answer about semicolons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26665514/42353).

Comment: And of course the function should not have a `return` at all: `fn test() -> u64 { unsafe { num() } }`.

Comment: That's a question of style, not correctness or morality.

Comment: I'm more than happy to dispense suggestions of style (and morality) as gospel. Besides, Clippy agrees with me .