# "cannot infer type for `T`" when using error enum variants

Tags: rust

I've got the following snippet:

```
 pub fn init(&mut self, opts: InitOptions) -> Result<(), PostalError> {
    let _ = self.mutex.lock();
    unsafe {
        if !libpostal_setup() {
            Err(PostalError::LibpostalSetup);
        }
    }
    self.setup_done = true;
    if opts.expand_address {
        unsafe {
            if !libpostal_setup_language_classifier() {
                Err(PostalError::LibpostalEnableExpansion);
            }
        }
        self.expand_address_enabled = true;
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

which yields this error when compiling:

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
--> src/lib.rs:110:17
 |
 110 |             Err(PostalError::LibpostalSetup);
 |                 ^^^ cannot infer type for `T`
```

I've tried a number of things:

1. Adding type annotations to `Err`, as suggested; e.g. `Err::<(), PostalError>(PostalError::LibpostalSetup);`, which compiles but produces warnings and incorrect runtime behavior (i.e. a single `unwrap()` no longer works on the returned `Result`).
2. Changing from the unit type `()` to `u8` (for testing).
3. Fiddling with enum variant signature changes in general in a variety of ways, to no avail.

What is curious is that I have another function on the same type, with a similar use of `Result` for which the compiler has no trouble with:

```
pub fn expand_address(
    &self,
    a: &str,
    opts: ExpandAddressOptions,
) -> Result<Expansions, PostalError> {
    if self.setup_done && self.expand_address_enabled {
        let _ = self.mutex.lock();
        unsafe {
            match CString::new(a) {
                Ok(c_string) => {
                    let addr = c_string.as_ptr() as *mut c_char;

                    let mut num_expansions: usize = 0;
                    let raw = libpostal_expand_address(addr, opts.opts, &mut num_expansions);
                    Ok(Expansions::new(raw, num_expansions))
                }
                Err(e) => Err(PostalError::BadCString(e)),
            }
        }
    } else {
        Err(PostalError::LibpostalNotReady)
    }
}
```

What exactly is the compiler is having issues with in the former example?

I could (and might) change to `Option<PostalError>`, but that makes the `match`/`unwrap`/`?` awkward to use. I'd rather not, if possible.

Comment: You've missed a `return`; the `Err(PostalError::LibpostalEnableExpansion);` is a (useless) statement, not a function's return value, so I guess Rust is saying it has no way of inferring `T` in `Result<T, PostalError>` you're trying to construct.

Comment: Interesting, I haven't actually had to use `return` yet. Any idea why it seems happy to accept `Err(PostalError::LibpostalNotReady)` in the second example?

Comment: I'm guessing it has something to do with it being the last case in the match arm, as well as the else branch being the end of the function. So the compiler is able to infer my intent there.

Comment: Your guess is correct; check out [the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch03-03-how-functions-work.html#function-bodies-contain-statements-and-expressions) and https://stackoverflow.com/a/26665514/1026

Comment: Thanks for the links, feel free to repost your comment as an answer to get accepted.

Comment: To be clear, `Result` does not get any special treatment by the compiler wrt control flow (ignoring the `?` syntax). So your first example is similar to `fn foo() -> u8 { if true { 0; }; 1 }` returning `1` as it's the last expression of the function, and your second example is like `fn foo() -> u8 { if true { 0 } }`, which returns `0` as the last expression of the function is the `if` expression, and its value is the value of the last expession in its `{ 0 }` block, which is `0`.

Comment: Yeah, I just hadn't read the manual in a long time. Makes perfect sense now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
 110 |             Err(PostalError::LibpostalSetup);
     |                 ^^^ cannot infer type for `T`
```

You missed a `return`.

`Err(PostalError::LibpostalSetup);` is a useless statement, not a function's return value, so I guess Rust is saying it has no way of inferring `T` in `Result<T, PostalError>` you're trying to construct.

"[Function Bodies Contain Statements and Expressions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch03-03-how-functions-work.html#function-bodies-contain-statements-and-expressions)" explains how the return value of a function is determined and "[Are semicolons optional in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26665471/are-semicolons-optional-in-rust/26665514#26665514)" explains the significance of semicolons, or lack thereof, in Rust.