# Why no semicolon after Ok(()) at the end of a function in rust?

Tags: rust, semicolon-inference

Code snippet taken from the documentation on [current_dir](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/env/fn.current_dir.html):

```rust
use std::env;

fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let path = env::current_dir()?;
    println!("The current directory is {}", path.display());
    Ok(())
}
```

I noticed that only by adding a semicolon after `Ok(())`, the program [does not compile](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b7f08bb3224c22980680af5008945db5) with the following error:

```rust
error[E0308]: mismatched types
expected enum `std::result::Result`, found `()`
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rust returns the value of the last expression.  When you add the semicolon after `Ok(())`, the final expression becomes a statement, so it's returning the "value" of the statement, which is a lack of value, also called `unit` (known as "()").

This question is also asked and answered here: [Are semicolons optional in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26665471/are-semicolons-optional-in-rust)

Expressions on rust documentation: https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rust-by-example/expression.html